# Timeout Mechanism for Hashtable

Tags: java, algorithm, timeout, hashtable

I have a hashtable that under heavy-traffic. I want to add timeout mechanism to hashtable, remove too old records. My concerns are,
- It should be lightweight 
- Remove operation has not time critical. I mean (timeout value is 1 hour) remove operation can be after 1 hour or and 1 hour 15 minute. There is no problem.

My opinion is,
I create a big array (as ring buffer)that store put time and hashtable key,
When adding to hashtable, using array index find a next slot on array put time, 
  if array slot empty, put insertion time and HT key,
  if array slot is not empty, compare insertion time for timeout occured.
     if timeout occured remove from Hashtable (if not removed yet)
     it not timeout occured, increment index till to find empty slot or timeouted array slot.
When removing from hashtable there is no operation on big array.

Shortly, for every add operation to Hashtable, may remove 1 timeouted element from hashtable  or do nothing.

What is your the more elegant and more lightweight solution ?

Thanks for helps,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should rather consider using a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or maybe a [`WeakHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).

The former has [a constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28int,%20float,%20boolean%29) to set the iteration order of its elements to the order of last access; this makes it trivial to remove too old elements. And its [`removeEldestEntry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) method can be overridden to define your own policy on when to remove the eldest entry automatically after the insertion of a new one.

The latter uses weak references to keys, so any key which has no other reference to it can be automatically garbage collected.

Comment: I plan to add timestamp to Hashmap value and check for timeout in removeEldestEntry function. Timeout control  also Just for check %10 insertion (not for all). This gives me better performance. I guess this is best for me :) Thanks for help.

Answer (score 9):

My approach would be to use the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) [`MapMaker`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html):

```
ConcurrentMap<String, MyValue> graphs = new MapMaker()
   .maximumSize(100)
   .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
   .makeComputingMap(
       new Function<String, MyValue>() {
         public MyValue apply(String string) {
           return calculateMyValue(string);
         }
       });
```

This might not be *exactly* what you're describing, but chances it's close enough. And it's much easier to produce (plus it's using a well-tested code base).

Note that you can tweak the behaviour of the resulting `Map` by calling different methods before the `make*()` call.

Comment: MapMaker is also available in Google Collections.

Comment: I have not tested yet but I guess this solution has too much extra weight.

Comment: @user196683: I've not tested your solution yet, but I guess your solution has quite a lot unknown, untested code and therefore probably quite a few unnecessary bugs. Now decide which could cost more: "guessed" "extra weight" or "guessed" extra bugs.

Comment: I just test insertion time hashtable vs ConcurrentMap, concurrentmap is more than twice time slower (using Single Thread) .

Comment: If your are planning to keep entries in the map for an hour, then I'm pretty sure that insertion speed will not be the limiting factor. Also: are you working in a single thread environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think a much easier solution is to use `LRUMap` from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). Of course you can write your own data structures if you enjoy it or you want to learn, but this problem is so common that numerous ready-made solutions exist. (I'm sure others will point you to other implementations too, after a time your problem will be choosing the right one from them :))

Comment: There are lots of put and remove operation. How to set capacity of LRUMAP ? If I set too big, timeouted element stay forever or set too small, how to sure that's element at least stored at 1 hour on hashtable.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you really needed. LRUMap is useful if you simply want to limit the size of your map. There's no expiry time, the least recently used entry is simply removed when you try to insert a new entry into a map already full. The capacity can be set in the constructor. But if you need to explicitly time entries out, the Guava solution is probably what you need.

Comment: LRUMap is limited apparently only by size, so it's not that good an option to use for time-sensitive limits.

Comment: @Mikko Wilkman True, but it wasn't at all obvious from the original question that the time limit is a requirement or just part of an attempted solution.

Comment: You can implement LinkedHashMap as LRU cache with a capacity limit.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey You can do pretty much whatever you like, my point really is that there are several out-of-the-box solutions for this problem family, there's no need to write one, unless you deliberately want to.

Comment: LinkedHashMap supports LRU out of the box. How you do it is documented in its Javadoc. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the currently most heavily accessed items in your cache structure are in the significant minority, you may well get by with randomly selecting items for removal (you have a low probability of removing something very useful).  I've used this technique and, in this particular application, it worked very well and took next to no implementation effort.