# Simple Java String cache with expiration possibility

Tags: java, concurrency, set

I am looking for a concurrent Set with expiration functionality for a Java 1.5 application. It would be used as a simple way to store / cache names (i.e. String values) that expire after a certain time.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that two threads should not be able to use the same name value within a certain time (so this is sort of a blacklist ensuring the same "name", which is something like a message reference, can't be reused by another thread until a certain time period has passed). I do not control name generation myself, so there's nothing I can do about the actual names / strings to enforce uniqueness, it should rather be seen as a throttling / limiting mechanism to prevent the same name to be used more than once per second.

Example:
Thread #1 does `cache.add("unique_string, 1)` which stores the name "unique_string" for 1 second.
If any thread is looking for "unique_string" by doing e.g. `cache.get("unique_string")` within 1 second it will get a positive response (item exists), but after that the item should be expired and removed from the set.

The container would at times handle 50-100 inserts / reads per second.

I have really been looking around at different solutions but am not finding anything that I feel really suites my needs. It feels like an easy problem, but all solutions I find are way too complex or overkill.

A simple idea would be to have a `ConcurrentHashMap` object with key set to "name" and value to the expiration time then a thread running every second and removing all elements whose value (expiration time) has passed, but I'm not sure how efficient that would be? Is there not a simpler solution I'm missing?

Comment: Why not have generated string ids which are not repeated at all, or not repeated within a given amount of time.  This way you won't have to keep track of previous ones.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize I should've been clearer on that part. I do not control the name generation myself. As an example we can say the name could be an IP adress, postal address or anything else and I'm looking to use the mechanism I'm asking for to throttle (i.e. not letting more than 1 unit per second be sent).

Comment: Similar to your problem, I hope help for your solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724323/timeout-mechanism-for-hashtable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating a Map where the item expires using a thread executor

```
//Declare your Map and executor service
final Map<String, ScheduledFuture<String>> cacheNames = new HashMap<String, ScheduledFuture<String>>();
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

You can then have a method that adds the cache name to your collection which will remove it after it has expired, in this example its one second. I know it seems like quite a bit of code but it can be quite an elegant solution in just a couple of methods.

```
ScheduledFuture<String> task = executorService.schedule(new Callable<String>() {
  @Override
  public String call() {
    cacheNames.remove("unique_string");
    return "unique_string";
  }
}, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
cacheNames.put("unique_string", task);
```

Comment: a version of this solution is what I chose to go for in the end. Simple, yet elegant. Thanks a lot for your valuable input!

Answer (score 5):

Google's Guava library contains exactly such cache: [CacheBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterWrite-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, looks very helpful! Actually when looking closer I can see this method is deprecated though and replaced by [CacheBuilder](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) which is in beta. I'll be having a look at this now and compare it to the solution @Shawn suggested. What I'm looking for is a "fire-and-forget" solution that won't have to make me think about memory management based on the number of calls I intend to do, based on that, would you say there is an advantage to any of the two solutions?

Comment: @Nils I checked in the version of guava that is in use in my company - but guava goes ahead so fast. I'll update the answer to not force future reader go the long way ;-)

Comment: @Nils Regarding hand-written solution using ScheduledFuture - I think it is less robust in that sense that it gives you exactly what it gives, but guava solution gives you a full hand of possible future versions improvements to this functionality. 

If you are in very restricted environment and using guava is not an option - use it of course, but in other case - consider using guava, and only in this particular case, but it is very handy library in general.

Comment: I agree going the Guava route (no problem in my environment) would be the preferred way, however, I just noticed that CacheBuilder is in version r10 of Guava which is not yet released :( So to proceed right now I need something else or need to rely on deprecated functionality. I wrapped a quick working example using @Shawn's suggestion and it seems to do OK, so perhaps if I abstract it away I can simply switch to Guava R10 once it's available. But do anyone have an idea about if performance would be an issue using a scheduled executor in the way suggested?

Comment: I would never advocate writing my own if there was a tried and tested open source solution. But I wouldn't use a depricated method and I wouldn't use beta code either. My solution is just an example of how it can be done. You can test it pretty easily and its not a difficult bit of code to follow. Since 1.5 threading has become a lot safer so I would think it would be an easy bit of code to implement and test well. I have implemented a similar solution in a financial platform which runs 24/7 and it works like a dream

Comment: @Nils, regarding performance, ease of use etc. - I thought that task of the answering people here is only to point you to the ways of solving problems, but not solving them for you. However I've tried to write a small test - https://gist.github.com/1234475 Unfortunately I have not managed implement Shawn Vader's solution with any acceptable performance. Also with my proposition there is a huge problem - it seems that putting elements into cache is possible only with CacheLoader passed into constructor. This is not very convinient API for your task. In the end, you is the decision maker here.

Comment: ShawnVader Your solution is what I eventually went for, so thanks a lot for that suggestion!
@IvanSopov I want to thank you a lot as well for your efforts in helping me, really helpful. CacheBuilder is definitely a good solution as soon as it's out of beta!

Answer (score 0):

A simple unique string pattern which doesn't repeat

```
private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis()*1000);
public static String generateId() {
     return Long.toString(COUNTER.getAndIncrement(), 36);
}
```

This won't repeat even if you restart your application.

Note: It will repeat after:

- you restart and you have been generating over one million ids per second.
- after 293 years.  If this is not long enough you can reduce the 1000 to 100 and get 2930 years.

Comment: Sorry Peter, but like I commented above I don't control name generation myself so it's not possible to change that part.

Answer (score 0):

It depends - If you need strict condition of time, or soft (like 1 sec +/- 20ms).
Also if you need discrete cache invalidation or 'by-call'.

For strict conditions I would suggest to add a distinct thread which will invalidate cache each 20milliseconds.

Also you can have inside the stored key timestamp and check if it's expired or not.

Comment: The condition of time is not strict. It should be "about" 1 second. Actually in this case, my strict requirement is that _at least_ one second must elapse until next attempt in using the same unique name, so I could very well configure the value to 1.2 seconds if the implementation could make it to be off by 20-200 ms, that's not a problem. Regarding discrete or by-call cache invalidation I have no real requirement if it solves my problem, since I could be doing 50-100 calls per second though memory management could be an issue I guess if not taken care of properly?

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the time for which  the key is blacklisted in the map (as [Konoplianko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500448/simple-java-string-cache-with-expiration-possibility/7500631#7500631) hinted)?

Something like this:

```
private final Map<String, Long> _blacklist = new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>() {
   @Override
   protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, Long> eldest) {
      return size() > 1000;
   }
};

public boolean isBlacklisted(String key, long timeoutMs) {
   synchronized (_blacklist) {
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Long blacklistUntil = _blacklist.get(key);
      if (blacklistUntil != null && blacklistUntil >= now) {
         // still blacklisted
         return true;
      } else {
         // not blacklisted, or blacklisting has expired 
         _blacklist.put(key, now + timeoutMs);
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The map would grow too big over time with the throughput level I deal with and I need something to automatically clean it up as well which is where the complexity is starting to grow and why I seek advice about a tested solution instead of necessarily rolling my own even if that wouldn't be too hard

Comment: Yes, a LinkedHashMap with a limited number of entries is better.